# How to add new layout for admin dashboard

Tags: php, zend-framework, mezzio

In Zend Expressive, the layout is "default" into "templates" folder.

I would like to add "admin" folder into "templates" folder like that:

- Templates

  - admin

    - app

      - admin-page.phtml
    - error

      - 404.phtml
      - error.phtml
    - layout

      - default.phtml
  - default

    - app

      - home-page.phtml
    - error

      - 404.phtml
      - error.phtml
    - layout

      - default.phtml

I've tried with the tutorials of Zend expressive to add new layout but no success for me...

```php
class AdminPageHandler implements RequestHandlerInterface
{
    private $template;


    public function __construct(TemplateRendererInterface $template)
    {
        $this->template = $template;
    }

    public function handle(ServerRequestInterface $request) : ResponseInterface
    {

        $data = [
            'admin' => 'layout::admin',
            // or 'layout::admin',
            // or 'layout::alternative',
        ];
        $content = $this->template->render('pages::admin-page', $data);
        return new HtmlResponse($content);
    }
}
```

How can I add a new layout for my admin dashboard?

I would like to add new layout for my admin dashboard because the HTML script is different of my Home Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template paths can be found in ConfigProvider class =>  __invoke method, under 'templates' => 'paths' or in getTemplates() method. There you should add a new path:

```
/**
     * Returns the templates configuration
     */
    public function getTemplates(): array
    {
        return [
            'paths' => [
                'app'    => [__DIR__ . '/../templates/app'],
                'error'  => [__DIR__ . '/../templates/error'],
                'layout' => [__DIR__ . '/../templates/layout'],
                'admin'  => [__DIR__ . '/../templates/admin'],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

then your handler should look something like this

```
public function handle(ServerRequestInterface $request) : ResponseInterface
    {

        $data = [
            'admin' => 'layout::admin',
            // or 'layout::admin',
            // or 'layout::alternative',
        ];
        $content = $this->template->render('admin::app/admin-page', $data);
        return new HtmlResponse($content);
    }
```